# TIME_TICK not called when minute changes

Tags: java, android

I am facing a problem that when the Time changes the TIME_TICK only called when the app is running. But i want to get it called even when app is running or not using broadcast receivers.

**Main Activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Checking", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      }
    }
```

**MyBroadastReceivers**

```
public class MyBroadastReceiversextends BroadcastReceiver
{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {

        Toast.makeText(arg0, "Toast Receive", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

**Menifest File**

```
    <receiver android:name="com.example.serviceschecking.MyBroadastReceivers" android:enabled="true" android:exported="true">  
       <intent-filter >
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIME_TICK"/>
       </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Answer (score 5):

As described in API You have to register this intent programmatically:

> Broadcast Action: The current time has changed. Sent every minute. You
>   can not receive this through components declared in manifests, only by
>   explicitly registering for it with Context.registerReceiver().

You have to register it for example in Your mainActivity:

```
      IntentFilter mTime = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK);
      registerReceiver(YourReceiver, mTime);
```

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_TIME_TICK):

> You can not receive this through components declared in manifests,
> only by explicitly registering for it with Context.registerReceiver()

Looking to your code, something like:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Checking", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

      receiver = new MyBroadastReceivers();
      registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK));
      }

      @Override
      protected void onDestroy() {
      // Unregister MyBroadastReceivers
      unregisterReceiver(receiver);
      }
    }
```

Plus, depending on what you want to do, AlarmManager may be a good alternative "particularly if you let the user configure the polling frequency". Please take a look in this this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19224905/broadcastreceiver-time-tick-dies-every-night).

Answer (score -2):

PErfact Example i have tested and worked perfactly

```html
package com.sifat.githubalarmapp;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Toast.makeText(context, "I am running sifat", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

```html
package com.sifat.githubalarmapp;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle; 

public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

    }



}
```

Add in manifest

```html
  <!-- Will not be called unless the application explicitly enables it -->
        <receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver"
            android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_TIME_TICK"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Comment: This no longer works.