# ACTION_TIME_TICK Broadcast not being caught inside AppWidgetProvider

Tags: android, widget, broadcastreceiver, broadcast

At first i thought that it would work as is, due to extending `BroadcastReciever`, however it does not.

So `onEnabled` I have registered it for the desired intent `ACTION_TIME_TICK`.

However, it is never received.

How can I correctly capture the broadcast, so that i can update the widget's clock, as well as refresh some values on my widget. Doing so on the minute mark is the ideal time.

```
public class Widget extends AppWidgetProvider {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        super.onReceive(context, intent);
        Log.v("WIDGET", "Recieved: " + intent.getAction());
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisabled(Context context) {
        super.onDisabled(context);
        //Turn off auto update
        context.unregisterReceiver(this);
    }

    @Override 
    public void onEnabled(Context context) {
        super.onEnabled(context);

        context.registerReceiver(this, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK));
        // Start auto update on Enable (widget exists)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should be crashing, as you cannot register a `BroadcastReceiver` from the `Context` supplied to a `BroadcastReceiver` via `onReceive()`. `AppWidgetProvider` is a subclass of `BroadcastReceiver`; methods like `onUpdate()` are called from its `onReceive()` method.

Even if this somehow no longer crashes like it used to, it will not work reliably. Your process can be terminated in milliseconds after `onUpdate()` returns.

You are welcome to add this `Intent` action to your `<intent-filter>` for your `Widget`. Just bear in mind that when you override `onReceive()`, if the action is not one that you are handling yourself, chain to the superclass, so `onUpdate()` and kin can be called.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. It doesn't crash for me at least (4.2.2), but nothing happens. I have `<action android:name="android.intent.action.TIME_TICK"/>` inside my `reciever`s `intent-filter`. But i read from your answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/19225701/940834 that it is pointless. Hence how i came to register broadcast instead. Unsure how to get this working. Should i be removing the registers?

Comment: @Doomsknight: Ah, I forgot that you can't register for that action via the manifest. I apologize for that. In short, there is no good way for you to do what you are trying to do. The list of bad ways includes `AlarmManager` and an everlasting service (where the service has the `registerReceiver()` code that you are trying to use in your `AppWidgetProvider`).

Comment: I have `AlarmManager` code working previously (wrote a few years ago). It fires at every 5 seconds, to ensure it updates at or just after the minute mark. (so the minute shows correctly on clock). I was looking to improving battery usage. I will revert my code to that, based on your suggestions. And see if I can get it to fire just after the minute instead. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @Doomsknight: You're probably already aware of this, but bear in mind that your code will not run on time on Android 6.0+ devices in Doze mode or if your app is in app standby mode.

Comment: I was not aware. Do you have any info i can read up on please. I can fire broadcasts from the app. To update the widget as required. It is just the clock that is a pain.. I thought `DigitalClock` would be a built in clock that changes automatically. But it just doesnt render my widget if i use it.

Comment: Found some :) http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html. I might just remove the clock. despite liking it